# I mentioned fix navbar in Bootstrap4. But Navbar is overflowing in my code

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I mentioned the bootstrap navbar fix code correctly. When I am scrolling the screen, my sections overflowing the navbar. Navbar is not yet fixed in the top of the page. Kindly confirm the changes should be made in bootstrap.min.css or we should change in HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>RaLas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/oldcss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>
      <!-- Start: Navigation Clean -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navigation-clean sticky-top">
        <div class="container"><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1"><img src="assets/img/Logo_name.png" style="margin-left: -5px;height: 40px;width: 200px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active navbar-text" href="#home" style="color: #205D84;"><strong>HOME</strong></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link navbar-text" href="#aboutus" style="color: #205D84;"><strong>ABOUT US</strong></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link navbar-text" href="#services" style="color: #205D84;"><strong>SERVICES</strong></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link navbar-text" href="#contactus" style="color: #205D84;"><strong>CONTACT US</strong></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End: Navigation Clean -->
    <section id="home" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;">
        <header id="homepage" class="masthead text-center text-white d-flex home" style="background-image: url(&quot;assets/img/homepage_Background_only.jpg&quot;);margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 0px;">
            <div class="container my-auto" style="margin-top: 161px;">
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 150px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 mx-auto" style="margin-top: -150px;"><img src="assets/img/Ralas_logo_homepage_png.png" style="width: 316px;">
                        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 7px;">Welcome to RaLas</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto" style="margin-top: 10px;"><a class="btn btn-primary text-center btn-xl js-scroll-trigger home_page_button button_hover" role="button" href="" style="background-color: rgba(22,138,221,0);padding-top: 5px;height: 30px;font-size: 15px;">Follow us</a></div>
                 <!-- Start: social media Icons -->
                    <div class="row" style="height: 400px;margin-top: 30px;">
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="height: 130px;">
                            <div class="login-card"><a href="#"><img class="profile-img-card" src="assets/img/insta.png" style="width: 60px;height: 60px;"></a>
                                <p class="profile-name-card" style="color:white">Instagram</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="height: 130px;">
                            <div class="login-card"><a href="#"><img class="profile-img-card" src="assets/img/facebook.png" style="width: 60px;height: 60px;"></a>
                                <p class="profile-name-card" style="color:white">Facebook</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <div class="login-card"><a href="#"><img class="profile-img-card" src="assets/img/whatsapp.png" style="width: 60px;height: 60px;"></a>
                                <p class="profile-name-card" style="color:white">Whatsapp</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End: social media Icons -->
            </div>
        </header>
    </section>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scrollscript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src='contatcjs/sampjs.js'></script>
    <script src='contatcjs/faq.js'></script>
    <script src="assets/js/script.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scrollscript.js"></script>
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $("form").submit(function(){
                alert("Submitted");
            });
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide us with more code. We cannot try and debug or replicate your issue with what you have given. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You haven't show us any of your HTML or CSS which is the thing you are asking about. Any why are you trying to use multiple versions of jQuery at the same time? `jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js`, `jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js`, `jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the class `navbar-fixed-top` with just `fixed-top` class in `<nav class>`

Comment: Have you wrapped everything under a `fluid container`